# Read minOccurs and default values from a WSDL file

Tags: c#, wsdl

I am coding a client for a web service. In the web service definition file, "minOccurs" and default values are defined. How can I access these minOccurs and defaults?

In the WSDL file, the element is defined like this:

`<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="optionalEntry" type="tns:optionalValueType" default="NULL"/>` where `optionalValueType` is an enumeration.

The web service is referenced as `webservice` and the value `NULL` can be set *manually* (like any other possible value) as `webservice.optionalValueType.NULL`.

Comment: I understand that the values can be derived from reading the XML data in the WSDL file. However this does not seems to be the meaning of WSDL. I would be surprised if these values could not be accessed within the object oriented structure of the class.

Answer (score 4):

Oversimplifying, WSDL describes an XML schema for documents which can be consumed by a web service endpoint. The `default` attribute is part of XML Schema standard, and the standard tells that value specified in this attribute should be automatically assigned to the element when no other value is specified (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_simple.asp).

There are some tools which can generate client side code from a given WSDL document. You didn't specify which tool you used, so I assume it is WSDL.exe (part of Visual Studio), but there are others (e.g. SoapUI). So, answer to your question depends on the tool you use.

Strictly speaking, the tools are not obliged to provide an API to expose value of `default` attribute. They should only generate code which will behave like defined in the standard, namely, if value is not specified, `default` value should be used. Example:

```
// Account property is defined like this:
// <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="account" type="s:string" default="FOO" />
var connInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
Console.WriteLine(connInfo.account); // Will print "FOO".
```

Going back to your question, I can see the following ways to get `default` value from the generated client code:

1. Create an instance of a class, then read the fields. The fields will be initialized to their `default` values (like in the code snippet above).
2. WSDL.exe adds `DefaultValueAttribute` to every property which has `default` value. Example (generated code):

```
public partial class ConnectionInfo 
{
    private string accountField;

    public ConnectionInfo() 
    {
        this.accountField = "FOO";
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute("FOO")]
    public string account 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.accountField;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.accountField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So it should be possible to get the value from that attribute, using some reflection:

```
var type = typeof(ConnectionInfo);
var prop = type.GetProperty("account");
var attr = (DefaultValueAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttributes(
    typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), true).First();
Console.WriteLine(attr.Value); // Will print "FOO".
```

As of `minOccurs` attribute, I cannot see a way to get it, other than reading the WSDL schema yourself.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2015 and add the webservice in the Project menu, Add service reference. So I guess that is WSDL.exe?

I can reproduce your first point. `webservice.serviceClass test = new webservice.serviceClass(); decimal a = test.testProperty;` works. However, I cannot reproduce your second point. There is no `test.testProperty.DefaultValueAttribute` available.

Comment: @MichaelWestwort, you are correct, Visual Studio uses wsdl.exe. I updated the answer with more details about reflection-based approach.